# How to edit files in a docker container when you don't have any text editor and you're not root?

Tags: docker, authentication, apt

I'm stuck at the login screen of Jenkins because I don't remember the username and the password to log in. I read in this article https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-reset-jenkins-admin-users-password/ that it is possible to solve this problem by editing the config.xml file.

But my problem is I don't have any text editor (vi, nano, emacs) and I can't install one with apt because I'm not root.

Anyone knows how to solve this issue ?

Thx !

Comment: You can use `docker cp` to copy files out of the container -- for editing -- and back into the container when you're done.

Comment: Unless the OS has been specially hardened, you should have access to ed, sed, awk, or other tools for modifying files on the remote host or in the container if you can get a shell with SSH or `docker exec`.

Comment: It's usually better practice to bind-mount configuration files from the host than to try to edit them in the container, since anything you do in the container filesystem will get lost as soon as the container exits.  If not being root is a problem, try adding a `-u root` option to your `docker run` command; if you're missing software, try `RUN apt-get install ...` in a custom Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

Thx Todd A. Jacobs !

I entered `sed -i -e "s/<useSecurity>true<\/useSecurity>/<useSecurity>false<\/useSecurity>/g" /var/jenkins_home/config.xml` and it worked just fine !

Not sure if it was the best way to solve the problem but it worked !